# Fancybox stopped working after migrating to Google's Blobstore

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My app runs on Google App Engine and I recently migrated the images used by the app to GAE's Blobstore. I noticed that after doing this, Fancybox no longer seems to be able to display my images in a lightbox frame.

My initialisation call for Fancybox in my template:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=fancypop]").fancybox({
        'titlePosition': 'over',
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
    });
});
```

... and then for an image:

```
<a rel="fancypop" href="{{ feature.get_image_url }}" title="{{ feature.title }}">
    <img class="bordered" src="{{ feature.get_humbnail_url }}" title="{{ feature.name }}" alt="Image of {{ feature.name }}"/>
</a>
```

The template variable `{{ feature.get_image_url }}` used to produce a url for the image like:

```
path/to/image/imagefile.jpg
```

...while now the url looks like:

```
http://lh5.ggpht.com/F8rcLKXR0vCNLBXUNL...
```

I presume that Fancybox gets confused by the new url format and is unable to "lightbox" the images. How can I solve this while retaining the images in the Blobstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have put a bit more effort in reading the Fancybox docs. The solution is quite simple. Just add the `type` argument to the init call:

```
$("a[rel=fancypop]").fancybox({
    'titlePosition': 'over',
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type': 'image'
...
```

This will make the lightbox feature work again...